# Code dynamisch erzeugen und ausführen auf Android

Tags: android

I want to write an Android application which generates the current View as well as the logic behind it (Activity) dynamically everytime it starts, based on a protocol which is loaded from a server. It is a form whose input fields can change daily. Thus, my question is whether it is possible on the Android platform to write an Interpreter class which dynamically generates code at runtime.

---

[Originial German question]

Hallo Leute

Ich möchte eine Android Applikation schreiben, die sich bei jedem start die aktuelle view sowie die Logik dahinter(activity) dynamisch generiert, basierend auf eienm Protokoll, dass zuvor von einem Server geladen wird. Es handelt sich dabei um ein Formular wo sich täglich eingabefelder ändern können. Meine Frage ist deshalb, ob es auf der Android Plattform möglich ist, eine Interpreterklasse zu schreiben die mir zur Laufzeit code dynamisch generiert.

lg Lx

Translation (condensed): Is it possible to create code dynamically at runtime on the android platform?

Comment: Translated via google translate: I want to write an Android application that start with each of the current view and the logic behind it (activity) is generated dynamically, based on several historic record that is first loaded from a server. It is a form where you can change daily input fields. My question is whether it is possible on the Android platform to write an interpreter class to me code at run time dynamically generated.

Answer (score 5):

While the easiest way to create a view is via the xml layout files, it is possible to create one in code.  Using this, you should be able to dynamically generate a view based on some input.  How complicated it is to generate really depends on how complicated the generated view should be.

I don't think you can easily generate a new Activity class, but if you have a defined set of behaviors your dynamic Activity class can act differently depending on the input.

Translated:
Während der einfachste Weg, eine Ansicht erstellen wird über die XML-Layout-Dateien ist es möglich, eine im Code erstellen. Mit diesem sollten Sie in der Lage, dynamisch zu generieren einen Blick auf einige Input. Wie kompliziert es ist, wirklich zu erzeugen, hängt von, wie kompliziert die erzeugte Ansicht sein sollte.

Ich denke nicht, kann man einfacher eine neue Tätigkeit Klasse, aber wenn Sie eine haben von Verhaltensweisen Ihre dynamische Aktivität Klasse anders handeln können, je nach Eingang definiert ist.

Comment: Ha, thanks.  Its the first time I was able to use Google translate for real. I have to say, the translation it produced in English looks pretty good (although I have no idea what the original actually said, but its coherent!)  All I had to do was paste it in, it told me it was German and produced the output.  Pretty cool.

Comment: Thank's for translating my question, because my english is realy bad (o:

Comment: I would be also happy for answers, how to generate dynamicaly code in an existing activity. Maybe some of you have an example, this would be very helpful for me. thanks lx